# Wagtail ImageChooserPanel: upload only, do not show other images in collections

Tags: file-upload, wagtail

I'm building a site with different users who should not see each others' uploaded images. The `wagtailimages.Image` model and `ImageChooserPanel` always show all the images in the various "collections".

How can I customize `ImageChooserPanel` so that it only offers image upload?

I can use a Django `models.ImageField` and its simple upload widget but then do not get the nice preview in an `Orderable` list, nor the different rendition sizes. A previous query on this goal was ill-informed: [Limit ImageChooserPanel to children of current Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204618/limit-imagechooserpanel-to-children-of-current-page) and now I realize it's basically a widget UX change I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this https://github.com/spapas/wagtail-faq/blob/master/README.md#ok-fine-but-i-dont-want-my-editors-to-be-able-to-select-small-images and this could help https://github.com/neon-jungle/wagtailmodelchooser